# Spring Boot JS and HTML files and packing to WAR file

Tags: spring-boot

I developed a server with spring boot. It has also one HTML and one JS file.
After packing the project to WAR file and running it, I get the error that the HTML cannot approach to the JS file.

```
java.io.FileNotFoundException: Jar URL cannot be resolved to absolute file path because it does not reside in the file system: war:file:/C:/Users/USER/Documents/workspace-sts-3.8.4.RELEASE/blabla/target/blabla-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.war*/storeFiles/app.js
```

How can I fix that?

Answer (score 0):

Where are your resource files located, in `src/main/webapp` or in `src/main/resources/static` ?
There has been an [issue](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/8986) on that topic.